# React Semantic UI Search component only accepts one character at a time (which also eliminates the previous input)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am using [search component](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/search/#types-standard-custom) from Semantic UI. When I console.log what I typed in the search field, only a single character is printed (**'abcd' will be printed as 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'**) and the search field doesn't show any character as if it doesn't take any input. But If I used `<Input> </Input>` instead, these problems are gone.
[code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-meadow-dsnzjs?file=/src/App.js) is here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as intended. Did you forget to actually set state?

```
const handleSearchChange = useCallback((e, data) => {
    setValue(data.value);
    setLoading(!loading);
  }, []);
```

Comment: You are right.. I thought the data.value is just the string input given to the search field, it will change as we type. But yes, update the state did solve the problem.